# Увеличение картинки по центру экрана при нажатии на imageview

Tags: java, android, изображения, imageview, glide

Необходимо при нажатии на картинку увеличить ее и разместить по центру(затемнив при этом задний фон), при повторном клике убирать на место.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что у вас есть потребность в функционале связанном с картинкой это конечно хорошо, но здесь принято кроме текста вопроса/проблемы показывать свои наработки чтобы отвечающим было проще от чего-то отталкиваться. В вашем случае я думаю вам подойдет обычный диалог где будет картинка, делаем для него разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goProDialogImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="350dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

добавляем слушатель нажатий на ваш маленький imageview:

```
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layou, null);
    dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


     ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.goProDialogImage);
   image.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
    dialog.show();
   
    }
});
```

при показе у вас этот кусок `((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap()`  вытаскивает картинку из вашего imageView на который вы нажимаете и устанавливает на виджет в диалоге картинку. Диалог убирается посредством нажатия на любое место. Так же можете добавить слушатель нажатий на картинку в диалоге и в тело слушателя добавить строку:

```
dialog.dismiss()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.